# How to speed up execution of many commands on a single server via SSH?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I need to run many commands on the same server via SSH using Paramiko.
How can I speed up the execution.

Multiple SSH connections? 
Is it possible to run commands in an asynchronous fashion? 
How can this be done with paramiko?

Commands that need to be executed are not correlated. One command does not depend on the output of another.

For example:

```
ssh root@172.16.2.40
docker containers ps  # get a list of containers 
for container_id in containers:
    docker inspect container_id # get details of each container
```

There maybe hundreds of docker containers running on a single server. 
docker API is not an option for me. So running command via SSH is the only way.

Comment: which commands? what's slow? what have you tried so far? details, details, details...

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see whats going on?

Comment: It's a general question. Suppose I need to run `ls` 100 times on a remote device. What's the fastest way of doing it? 
How can I create multiple connections with paramiko?

Comment: It's easier for us to give you useful answers if you are asking about a specific situation, particularly when you have first tried solving something yourself and can provide the code that's not working as you expect.  There may be several ways of speeding up remote command execution over ssh, but which is best may depend on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @larsks thanks, I've edited my question.

Comment: Can you make the docker socket remotely available, either over `tcp://` and then connect to that with a docker client? If you don't want to expose that socket to the whole world, you can use SSH tunneling to temporarily make that socket available. Something like `ssh -nNT -L $(pwd)/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock user@someremote` and then `export DOCKER_HOST=$(pwd)/docker.sock`